# What is the general availability of rooms in Malta during the low season?

Tags: accommodation, malta

I used to go to Greece in the preseason and rooms to let was normally very easy (just go to the harbor or walk through some city and plenty of options available).

I wonder if this is true also for Malta in half/end September period?

Comment: I meant a single room, just for me and my gf. However, we already booked something (via booking.com), didn't want to take the risk not having rooms to let available or paying full price hotels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bring this question to an answered state, I have a good friend in Malta who lives in Valletta and has a vacation flat in Birzebbugia.  I put the question to her exactly as you asked it.

Presumably by 'city' and 'harbour' you mean Valletta.  You cannot rely upon walking through the city to find vacant rooms.  You may luck out or may not, but in Valletta the odds are against you.  In the other cities you may need a working knowledge of Maltese to read the signs outside the smaller B&B type of lodging opportunities.

On the plus side, if one proprietor takes you in, then you are pretty well set for the rest of Malta with their referrals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this is than different than most Greek islands where you can just walk around and find enough rooms to let (at least in the pre/after season).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, right! But remember that the south side of Malta is turning in to a horrible place and people are squeezing in to the north side as a trend

Comment: You mean refugees from Africa?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, yes, the camps